# How can i make equal spaces between the squad members in the circle formation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When it's square formation i can set the space fine.
But i'm not sure how to do it with the circle formation.
Inside the FormationSquare method i'm using the space variable for the square formation. Now i need to do the same idea for the circle formation too.

Maybe inside the RandomCircle to change something and using the space variable ?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SquadFormation : MonoBehaviour
{
    enum Formation
    {
        Square, Circle
    }

    public Transform squadMemeber;
    public int columns = 4;
    public int space = 10;
    public int numObjects = 20;
    public float yOffset = 1;

    private Formation formation;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        formation = Formation.Square;
        ChangeFormation();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            GameObject[] objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Squad Member");
            if (objects.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (GameObject obj in objects)
                    Destroy(obj);
            }

            ChangeFormation();
        }
    }

    private void ChangeFormation()
    {
        switch (formation)
        {
            case Formation.Square:

                for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
                {
                    Transform go = Instantiate(squadMemeber);
                    Vector3 pos = FormationSquare(i);
                    go.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + pos.x, 0, transform.position.y + pos.y);
                    go.Rotate(new Vector3(0, -90, 0));
                    go.tag = "Squad Member";
                }
                formation = Formation.Circle;
                break;

            case Formation.Circle:

                Vector3 center = transform.position;
                for (int i = 0; i < numObjects; i++)
                {
                    Vector3 pos = RandomCircle(center, 5.0f);
                    var rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(center - pos);
                    pos.y = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(pos);
                    pos.y = pos.y + yOffset;
                    Transform insObj = Instantiate(squadMemeber, pos, rot);
                    insObj.rotation = rot;
                    insObj.tag = "Squad Member";
                }
                formation = Formation.Square;
                break;
        }
    }

    Vector2 FormationSquare(int index) // call this func for all your objects
    {
        float posX = (index % columns) * space;
        float posY = (index / columns) * space;
        return new Vector2(posX, posY);
    }

    Vector3 RandomCircle(Vector3 center, float radius)
    {
        float ang = Random.value * 360;
        Vector3 pos;
        pos.x = center.x + radius * Mathf.Sin(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        pos.z = center.z + radius * Mathf.Cos(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        pos.y = center.y;
        return pos;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Even distribution of objects on circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45552153/even-distribution-of-objects-on-circle)

Comment: Have you considered splitting your circle up into segments and just iterating through the squad to place them around the circumference?

Comment: @Serlite no but that's logic. Can you show example please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that your `RandomCircle()` method is...well, random. You're just arbitrarily grabbing an angle around the circle, without any regard for where other squad members have been placed, meaning they'll practically never be evenly distributed.

Consider calculating the angle that will separate each squad member (if distributed evenly) beforehand, then perform a similar approach to `FormationSquare()` where you iterate through the squad to distribute them.

This may be a bit closer to what you want (basing this on the assumption that `RandomCircle()` already works as designed):

```
Vector3 FormationCircle(Vector3 center, float radius, int index, float angleIncrement)
{
    float ang = index * angleIncrement;
    Vector3 pos;
    pos.x = center.x + radius * Mathf.Sin(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    pos.z = center.z + radius * Mathf.Cos(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    pos.y = center.y;
    return pos;
}
```

To call it, you'd do:

```
Vector3 center = transform.position;
float radius = (float)space / 2;
float angleIncrement = 360 / (float)numObjects;

for (int i = 0; i < numObjects; i++)
{
    Vector3 pos = FormationCircle(center, radius, i, angleIncrement);
    // ...
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Working nice. When i set the space value for 50 it's fine on the Circle formation but then it's too big/wide on the square formation. The space between the squad members on square is not the same as on circle. Should i make another space variable for the square formation ? For example space variable value 50 is fine for the circle but too big for the square.

Comment: @DragonFlea I think it'd be fine if you split up the values, or found a better relationship between the space values they require - part of the problem is that while the squad members fill up the square formation, they're only distributed around the edge of the circle formation. You could probably retain the same space value if they filled the circle, but that would require calculating using a variable number of concentric circles - which would be a lot more work to devise in a scaleable way.